# p:dataTable unselect row without using meta key (selecting works)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm using:

Server: Wildfly 8.2
JSF: 2.2
Primefaces: 5.2
JDK:8

I have a datatable with multiple selection. I use `rowSelectMode='add'` so clicking on different rows without modifier keys adds new rows instead of unselecting all selected ones.

```
<p:dataTable id="table"
          value="#{ixController.files}"
         var="item" paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink}
                                {PageLinks}
                                {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
         selection="#{ixController.selecteds}"
         rowKey="#{item.id}"
         rowSelectMode="add"
         selectionMode="multiple">

<p:column headerText="Files">
    #{item.fileName}
</p:column>
```

As stated it works fine for adding rows, however I need to press Ctrl to unselect rows, and the customers wish to just click again on the row and unselect it.

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Use check box instead that way they can select and un-select just by clicking it, follow Prime Faces example:

```
<p:dataTable id="checkboxDT" var="car" value="#{dtSelectionView.cars6}" selection="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCars}" rowKey="#{car.id}" style="margin-bottom:0">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Checkbox
        </f:facet>
        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Year">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Brand">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Color">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
        </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton process="checkboxDT" update=":form:multiCarDetail" icon="ui-icon-search" value="View" oncomplete="PF('multiCarDialog').show()" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: thank you =) 
However in this case I cannot use checkbox =/

Comment: In that case I guess you'll have to handle the event by hand with:
In your managed bean:

 `public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        event.getObject();//temper with the object here.
    }`

In you XHTML:

`<p:dataTable listener="#{ixController.onRowSelect}" />`

can't test here, but if you send the type of object the listener returns, I can try to figure it out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support. the type is a simple DTO like:
`
public class FileList {
  private int id;
  private String fileName;
`

I tried something like this:

`
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
  FileList o = (FileList) event.getObject();
  if (selecteds.contains(o)) {
   selecteds.remove(o);
  }
 }
`

but it passes here after the selection. So the first time it selects and then unselects =/

Answer (score 0):

I cant find an attiribute for this, however, there is a way:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{groupBean.groups}" var="grp" rowKey="#{grp.id}"
     selectionMode="single" selection="#{groupBean.group}">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{groupBean.onRowSelect}" update="@all" />
```

As you see, when a row clicked, `selectedItem` setted to `groupBen.goup` object.

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    if (prevGroupId == group.getId())
        group = new PersonelGroup();
    else
        prevGroupId = group.getId();
}
```

In `onRowSelect` method, you can check if user click same row for the second time by comparing previous selected item id. And by instanciating `group` object to new, DataTable has been updated to no selection state.

It is important to not forget to add `update="@all"` attiribute of DataTable.

Comment: Sorry, Misread the original question (did your answer thoroughly). `update="@all"` seems a bit to broad though. If just updating the datatable does not work, add a panel around it and update that.

Comment: Thank you @Kukeltje `update="@all"` not necessary as you mention. `update=":formDataTable :anotherForm"`is enough to rerender DataTable and other form if needed.